# Laravel Blade @stack minify javascript

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I'm using Laravel `@push` and `@stack` features to insert some js code in the templates.

```
@push('js')
var foo = 100
@endpush
```

In the template I'm displaying it with  `@stack('js')`

Is there a way to extend `@stack` so I can minify the javascript code before is displayed?